# TFS2018 get build definition modified date

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am using the TFS2018 API to get all build definitions. I would like to know the last time a build definition was changed (also if build steps are changed).

To explain this better. I am using the API to batch update build definitions e.g. 100 build definition based on a template. If I change the template I will remove all the definition and create a new one based on the template. However if a specific build template is changed manually using the web admin page I don´t want to remove it because it has been customized.

I assume the revision is only created during a build. But there is a possibility that a user changes the build definition without building it.

Therefore I was hoping there would be a modified date whenever something is changed in a build definition?

UPDATE: I always get the same respone, an empty array, when calling the revision REST API
"{\"count\":0,\"value\":[]}"
"https://mytfsdomain/tfs/DefaultCollection/MyTeamProject/_apis/build/definitions/7332/revisions?api-version=2.0"

Even if I change the build definition 7332 I still get the same response. Any idea why there are no revisions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`api-version=4.1` is for VSTS. Since you are using TFS 2018, you need to use `api-version=4.0`:

```
Get http://TFS2018:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/TeamProject/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}/revisions?api-version=4.0
```

I also tried `api-version=2.0`, it works as well. Check the screenshot below:

[image]

In addition, you could check the **History** tab when you edit the build definition, you could get changed date there too:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This will require a few REST calls using the [revisions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/definitions/get%20definition%20revisions) API:

`GET https://{url}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}/revisions?api-version=4.1`

The revision number is one of the optional parameters when retrieving a build definition, so you can retrieve a specific revision of the build definition and compare against the latest.

Comment: Hi @DanielMann thanks for your reply I updated my question to better explain what I want to achieve.

Comment: @doorman Your update changes nothing about the validity of the answer. You can get the revisions from the revisions API. Every time you change a build definition whether via the REST API or via clicking the "Save" button in the build editor, it creates a new revision.

Comment: Hi @DanielMann thanks, however I am not getting any revisions even if I update the build definitions. I am only getting an empty array.  I am actually using API version 2.0 should that matter? I updated my questions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to query for the [definition revisions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/definitions/get%20definition%20revisions). The JSON that gets returned contains the details of the changes. Depending on what you are using to parse the output, grab the last element of the `value` array and then grab the `changedDate` field. I also believe the value returned is UTC. Below is some PowerShell to help you out.

```
$pat = "[Your PAT]"
$vstsServiceCredentials = ":$pat"

$encodedVstsServiceCredentials = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($vstsServiceCredentials))
$authorizationHeader = @{ Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f 
$encodedVstsServiceCredentials) }

$buildService = "https://[accountName].visualstudio.com/[projectName]/_apis/build/definitions/[BuildDefinitionId]/revisions?api-version=4.1"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $buildService -Method Get -Headers 
$authorizationHeader

Write-Host $response
Write-Host $response.value[$response.value.Length - 1].changedDate
```

Comment: Hi @virusstorm thanks for your reply I updated my question to better explain what I want to achieve.